# Returning multiple values already declared in class (java)

Tags: java

First of all, I'm a big beginner. And this is a homework I am struggling to deal with - I don't need the best and rubust solution, but the simplest one. Thank you for your time, everyone reading.

So, I have these attributes:

```
public int identifikace;
public String druh;
public int vek;
public Majitel majitel;
```

used in constructor that looks like this:

```
public Zvire(int identifikace, String druh, int vek, Majitel majitel){
    this.identifikace = identifikace;
    this.druh = druh;
    this.vek = vek;
    this.majitel = majitel;
}
```

Wrote some small easy one-trick getters (

```
 public int getIdentifikace(){
    return identifikace;
}
```

), yet now I should create a method that returns text with *identifikace*, *druh*, *vek* and *majitel* - all as a String.

Returning multiple attributes apparently doesn't work. How should I do that then? Arraylist appears to be a possible solution, but I don't know how to use it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want your method to return a single string which is concatenation of all values or all values separately?

Comment: Would you mind going through both solutions, please? At least I'd learn something more - if not though, concatenation should be enough.

Comment: What about String concatenation ?  :)

Answer (score 1):

OMG question, so....

Return as String:

```
class Test {
String a;
String b
int c

    String getThat () {
       return a+b+c
    }

}
```

Better, using StringBuilder:

```
class Test {
String a;
String b
int c

    String getThat () {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       builder.append(a);
       builder.append(b);
       builder.append(c);
       return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Want return as tuples? Use generics:

```
class Test {
String a;
String b
int c

public static class Tuples <A, B, C> {
  A a; B b; C c;
  Tuples (A a, B b, C c) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
  this.c = c
  }

 A getA () {
  return a;
  }

 //And so on.....

}

    Tuples<String, String, Integer> getThat () {
       Tuples<String, String, Integer> tuples = 
       new Tuples (a, b, c);
       return tuples;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher probably wants you to return them in 1 String.

In java, you can simply concatenate integers with string like

```
String s = "abc";
int i = 5;
s + i; // returns abc5
```

If you want to convert an object to a String, you need to use the built-in toString method.

So, to create your String, you need to do

```
String s = identifikace + " " + druh + " " + vek + " " + majitel.toString();
```

If you want to return them separately as 4 Strings in 4 different methods, you can simply use the above solution but without concatenation.

Hint: a hacky way to convert an int to a String is to concatenate it with "" (empty String)

Note: If toString isn't overridden, then it returns the hash of the object, if you want it tk return something custom, override it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all classes extend from the `Object` super class, which makes available the `toString()` method. The aim of this method is to provide functionality which allows the object to return a string representation of itself.

In your case, what you would need to do would be to `override` this method and make it return a single string made up from the data you have mentioned. In this case, you do not need to return multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

separate  values with `|` symbol.

```
public static String getAllProperties(){
return  identifikace +"|"+druh +"|"+vek+"|"+majitel;

}
```

sample access method:

```
public accessProperties()
{

String allValues=YOURCLASSNAME.getAllProperties();
    for (String retval: allValues.split("|")){
         System.out.println(retval);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

> create a method that returns text with identifikace, druh, vek and
>   majitel - all as a String

Means something like

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %s %s %s", identifikace, druh, vek, majitel); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method which returns attributes as text:

```
public String toString() {
   return "" + identifikace + druh + vek + majitel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> yet now I should create a method that returns text with identifikace, druh, vek and majitel - all as a String.

That is a hint for your method signature: you want to write a method that returns a `String`. In fact, this kind of a requirement is so common that every Java object gets this for free in the form of an already implemented [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) called: `public String toString()`.

This default method is however not that useful. So, you override that method this way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + this.identifikace + " " + this.druh + ...
}
```

This works because of the concatenation operator `+`. There are better ways of concatenating various objects, but the idea is that you "serialize" the object's state in the form of a string.

You should use encapsulation properly in your class. You are declaring your fields as `public` and yet providing getters for them. This is quite needless. Make your fields private.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a java guy but what about -

```
 public string getIdentifikace(){
this.identifikace.toString()+","+this.druh +","+ this.vek.toString()+"," +this.majitel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have multiple ways to do this. But one simple way is to override `toString()` method of `Object` class as   `@nipinti` suggested. Here is an implementation to that.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return (this.identifikace+":"+this.druh+":"+this.vek+":"+this.majitel);
}
```

And here is another implementation using `ArrayList`(As you want to learn that way also)

```
public List<Object> getAll(){
    List list=new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(this.identifikace);
    list.add(this.druh);
    list.add(this.vek);
    list.add(this.majitel);
    return list;
}
```

And in your class containing main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ............

    List list= new YourClass().getAll();   

    ............
}
```

And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) is the link to understand more about `List` interface
and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) is the link to understand it's implementations like `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.